Add ubiquitous timestamp hover to 'Last seen' information for moderators
After the profile page was made responsive, the Last seen information was intentionally made less granular except for ♦ moderators. We can still see when someone was last active a couple of minutes ago:

even though you would probably see 'this week'.

For moderators, it's pretty useful to determine whether we can delete a comment reply that has flagged as 'no longer needed' - if the intended recipient hasn't been seen after that comment was posted, it's usually still relevant.
This works fine, except that I'm missing the hover that shows the exact UTC timestamp, which is present on almost all relative timestamps in the network (hover over my member age to check it yourself). While us moderators are able to subtract 11 minutes from the current time, "Last seen yesterday" may not provide enough information. (After 60 minutes, it's measured in hours; after 24 hours, in days.)
There's a "user dashboard" with more moderator-specific information about the user, which does have a "Last seen" field with the same granularity as the main profile page and it does have that UTC timestamp hover. Can it be added to the main profile widget please?
